# Nginx subdomain proxypass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, subdomain

I want to redirect non-ssl traffic to ssl for all subdomains. I want to keep the subdomain the same. I want to specify a different `proxy_pass` for staging.foo.com. I only have 3 things going right now `foo.com`, `www.foo.com` and `staging.foo.com`. I want to proxy pass the bare domain and the www to localhost 8000. And proxy pass the `staging` subdomain to localhost 8001.

```
http://foo.com/ -> https://foo.com/ -proxy-> 127.0.0.1:8000
http://www.foo.com/ -> https://www.foo.com/ -proxy-> 127.0.0.1:8000
http://staging.foo.com/ -> https://staging.foo.com/ -proxy-> 127.0.0.1:8001
```

With the following, it looks like all traffic to `www` or `staging` gets redirected to the bare domain. What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name foo.com www.foo.com staging.foo.com;
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name foo.com www.foo.com;
        # ...
        location / {
          proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
          # ...
        }
}
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name staging.foo.com;
        # ...
        location / {
          proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
          # ...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change first `server {}` section to:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name foo.com www.foo.com staging.foo.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Note `$server_name` --> `$host`, this is a solution of your problem. Replacement of `redirect` to `return` is not necessary, but much better.